# Object still animates despite not having any keyframes in dope sheet or timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, dopesheet

Despite having no keyframes on my dope sheet or timeline (or anywhere that I can find) my object still animates when I press play. There is one keyframe at the beginning I added, but even if I delete it the object still moves when I hit space. This whole thing started when I used automatic keyframing (the record button) and I couldn't move the keyframes I made with recording.

Also, how do I move keyframes from automatic recording after I have created them? I want to animate by just moving the armature's pose and the frame head, then move the frames I have created with recording.

https://easyupload.io/y149vb

Comment: Have you check you NLA track? you probably hae something there

Comment: @Emir You're right, I was just writing an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Nonlinear Animation* editor there is a track in the channel "Object". This is animating your armature.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I have literally spent about half a week trying to fix this animation, and two days on this specific issue.